# I have an issue with this tag . The dropdown componet from laravel breeze starter kit doen't work

Tags: laravel, dropdown, breeze, slot

I have an issue with this tag .
The dropdown componet from laravel breeze starter kit doen't work

I thing the problem is the `<x-slot name="trigger">` .
does anyone face this problem again?

where is slot tag located? I thing the problem comes from there

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

When you use slot tag the important thing is variable name, here you should looking for `trigger` variable in your layout.
read more here https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#slots
in new version of laravel we also use this syntax `<x-slot:trigger>`